# Does anyone know of a proof ot the recursion for Legendre polynomials which follows directly from Gram Schmidt?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

If we start with the functions $\{1,x,x^2,...\}$ on $[-1,1]$ and apply the Gram-Schmidt process, we obtain the nonnormalized Legendre Polynomials. Does anyone know a proof of the recursive relation
$$
(n+1)P_{n+1}(x) = (2n+1)xP_n(x)-nP_{n-1}(x)
$$
which uses nothing more than this, and which does not depend on the differential equation, the generating function, Rodrigues' formula, etc?

Comment: There was one in a recent copy of Resonance.

Comment: http://www.ias.ac.in/resonance/php/toc.php?vol=18&issue=02

Answer (score 3):

This an answer to the version of the question given in Mike's comment. Note first that for any polynomials $p$ and $q$ we have $(xp,q)=(p,xq)$. Second, note that $P_n$ is orthogonal to all polynomials of degree less than $n$.

So if $m \le n-2$, then
$$
  (xP_n,P_m) = (P_n,xP_m) = 0.
$$

But we know that $xP_n$ must be a linear combination of $P_0,\ldots,P_n,P_{n+1}$
(because this holds for any polynomial of degree at most $n+1$), and the coefficient of $P_m$ in this expansion if $(xP_,P_m)/(P_m,P_m)$. Therefore $xP_n$ is a linear combination of $P_{n-1}$, $P_n$ and $P_{n+1}$.

Finally note that this works for any family of orthogonal polynomials, not just Legendre polynomials.

Comment: Thanks,Chris. That's exactly what I need. I was stuck on whether P_n was orthogonal to all polynomials of lower degree. Sometimes, the way for me to realize that something is "obvious" is simply to read someone else say that it is obvious!

Answer (score 1):

Let $(f,g)=\int_{-1}^1f(x)g(x)\,dx$ denote the $L^2$ inner product.

We seed the process with $P_0(x)=1,P_1(x)=x$. We'll prove this by induction and try to first prove $n=2$. We know $P_2(x)$ satisfies $(P_2,P_0)=\int_{-1}^1 P_2(x)\cdot 1=0$ and $(P_2,P_1)=\int_{-1}^1 P_2(x)\cdot x=0$. We don't actually have a normal condition on this basis, though Gram-Schmidt has built into it a normalising process after every step.

So instead we're just going to prove that this recursive relation starts building up an orthogonal basis.  We have $P_2(x)=x^2-\frac{(x^2,1)}{(1,1)}1-\frac{(x^2,x)}{(x,x)}x$. This gives us
$$
\frac{(x^2,1)}{(1,1)}=\frac{\int_{-1}^1 x^2\,dx}{\int_{-1}^1 1\,dx}=\frac{2/3}{2}=\frac{1}{3},\quad \frac{(x^2,x)}{(x,x)}=\frac{\int_{-1}^1 x^3\,dx}{\int_{-1}^1 x^2\,dx}=0 \\
P_2(x)=x^2-\frac{1}{3}\cdot1-0\cdot x=x^2-\frac{1}{3}.
$$

But this doesn't agree with the second Legendre polynomial. Maybe I messed up in here, but at least I'll post this here for you to ponder.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The reason your polynomial does not agree with the 2nd degree Legendre polynomial is that the Legendre polynomials are "normalized" so that P_n(1)=1 for all n, rather than being normalized to have vector space norm 1.                                                              But I basically would like to know if there is an elementary proof that xP_n is a linear combination of P_(n-1) and P_(n+1).